# How to call a method from dbhelper in broadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to excute a method in my dbhelper immediately my alarm service run, the if that code runs successfully I want to display a notification based on the result of the method execution. I want this to run even if my app is idle or in the background

this is my broadcastReceiver

```
public class ExpiryBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //db helper
    private DbHelper dbHelper;

    private final String CHANNEL_ID = "expiring_items";
    private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 200;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            dbHelper.updateExpiryRow();
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_item_expiring)
                        .setContentTitle("ProExm Product Expiry")
                        .setContentText("Some products will soon expire, check now...")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

        }

    }


}
```

this is my alarmmanager

```
 public void startAlertAtParticularTime() {

        // alarm first vibrate at 14 hrs and 40 min and repeat itself at ONE_HOUR interval

        intent = new Intent(this, ExpiryBroadcast.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 280192, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 02);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm will vibrate at time specified",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

I have this code in my dbhelper class which I want to run before notification even if my application is asleep or in the background

```
  public void updateExpiryRow(){

        int daysToExpiry = 0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.ITEMS_TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //looping through all records and add to list
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                ModelItems modelItems = new ModelItems(
                        ""+cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_ID)),
                        ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_ITEM_NAME)),
                        ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_ITEM_IMAGE)),
                        ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_ITEM_PRICE)),
                        ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_ITEM_MANUFACTURER)),
                        ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_DESC)),
                        ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_EXPIRY_DATE)),
                        ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_MANUFACTURE_DATE)),
                        Integer.parseInt(""+cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_DAYS_TO_EXPIRY)))-1,
                        ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_ADDED_TIMESTAMP)),
                        ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.C_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP))
                );

                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
                DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

                try {
                    Date date = formatter.parse(modelItems.getItemExp());
                    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
                    String text = now.format(formatter2);
                    Date dateNow = formatter.parse(text);
                    long diffInMillies = Math.abs(date.getTime() - dateNow.getTime());
                    long diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    daysToExpiry = (int) (long) diff;
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                // id will be inserted automatically as we set AUTOINCREMENT in query

                //insert data
                String timestamp = ""+System.currentTimeMillis();
                values.put(Constants.C_ID, modelItems.getId());
                values.put(Constants.C_ITEM_NAME, modelItems.getItemName());
                values.put(Constants.C_ITEM_IMAGE, modelItems.getItemImage());
                values.put(Constants.C_ITEM_PRICE, modelItems.getItemPrice());
                values.put(Constants.C_ITEM_MANUFACTURER, modelItems.getItemManufacturer());
                values.put(Constants.C_DESC, modelItems.getItemDesc());
                values.put(Constants.C_EXPIRY_DATE, modelItems.getItemExp());
                values.put(Constants.C_MANUFACTURE_DATE, modelItems.getItemMfd());
                values.put(Constants.C_DAYS_TO_EXPIRY, daysToExpiry);
                values.put(Constants.C_ADDED_TIMESTAMP, modelItems.getAddedTime());
                values.put(Constants.C_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP, timestamp);

                //insert row, it will return record id of saved record
                db.update(Constants.ITEMS_TABLE, values, Constants.C_ID +" = ?", new String[] {modelItems.getId()});
                //add record to list
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        //close db connection
        db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to initialize the dbHelper

```
dbHelper = new DbHelper();
```

Then just call your method.

And this broadcast receiver will work if your app is idle or even closed

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a foreground service and start it from your broadcast receiver, it will work even if the app is killed, and in your service, you can instantiate your DbHelper and execute what you want, after finishing tasks just stop it.